# Умножение массивов

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Есть 3 массива end, suff, pre

```
Array
(
    [end] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => ый
        )

)

Array
(

    [suff] => Array
    (   
        [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => енн
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => нн
        )

)

Array
(

    [pre] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => а
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => ан
        )
    )
)
```

Вопрос как их перемножить, не значения разумеется, а массивы.
Другими словами, как в конечном итоге выдать 1ин массив, со всеми возможными вариациями чередования значение этих массивов.

Answer (score 3):

```
$yourArray = array($pre, $suff, $end);
```

Разве, нет?

**P.S.** могу что-то с C# путать)

Но, вот это точно будет рабочим вариантом:

```
$yourArray = array(
                     array('а', 'ан'),
                     array('енн', 'нн'),
                     array('ый'),
);

echo $yourArray[0][0].$yourArray[1][0].$yourArray[2][0] // аенный
//и т.д.
```

Comment: Некрофилии псто.
Нет, Ваш пример можно назвать "сложением". Мне тогда требовалось что-то типо mysql'овского аналога cross join (перекрестное объединение).

Answer (score 0):

То что вам нужно :

> `$allstring =`
>
> `true` - перемножает все элементы,
>
> `false` - перемножает так же и не полные части.

```
public static function doMultiply($array, $allstring)
{
    $outArray = [];
    $sizeOfArray = sizeof($array);
    $countOfArray = count($array);
    for ($p = $sizeOfArray - 1; $p >= 0; $p--) {
        if ($allstring) {
            $p = 0;
        }
        for ($firstkey1 = $sizeOfArray; $firstkey1 < $sizeOfArray * 2; $firstkey1++) {
            $firstkey = $firstkey1 - $p;
            if ($p == 0) {
                $firstkey1 = $sizeOfArray * 2;
            }
            if ($firstkey >= $countOfArray) {
                $firstkey = $firstkey - count($array);
            }

            $combinations = 1;
            $array2 = array();
            $array2 = $array;

            for ($key = $firstkey; $key < $p + $firstkey; $key++) {
                $key1 = $key;
                if ($key1 >= $countOfArray) {
                    $key1 = $key1 - $countOfArray;
                }
                unset($array2[$key1]);
            }

            $array2 = array_values($array2);

            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array2); $i++) {
                $combinations *= sizeof($array2[$i]);
                $currentKeys[$i] = 0;
            }
            $n = sizeof($array2) - 1;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $combinations; $i++) {
                $string = null;
                for ($k = 0; $k < sizeof($array2); $k++) {
                    $string .= $array2[$k][$currentKeys[$k]] . " ";

                }
                $outArray[] = trim($string);
                $currentKeys[$n]++;

                for ($k = sizeof($array2) - 1; $k >= 0; $k--) {
                    if ($currentKeys[$k] >= sizeof($array2[$k])) {
                        $currentKeys[$k] = 0;
                        if ($k - 1 >= 0) {
                            $currentKeys[$k - 1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $outArray;
}
```